# Process a file using hash

Tags: ruby

Below is the input file that I want to store into a hash table, sort it and output in the format shown below.

Input File

```
Name=Ashok, Email=ashok85@gmail.com, Country=India, Comments=9898984512
Email=raju@hotmail.com, Country=Sri Lanka, Name=Raju
Country=India, Comments=45535878, Email=vijay@gmail.com, Name=Vijay
Name=Ashok, Country=India, Email=ashok37@live.com, Comments=8898788987
```

Output File (Sorted by Name)

```
Name Email Country Comments
-------------------------------------------------------
Ashok ashok37@live.com India 8898788987
Ashok ashok85@gmail.com India 9898984512
Raju raju@hotmail.com Sri Lanka
Vijay vijay@gmail.com India 45535878
```

---

So far, I have read the data from the file and stored every line into an array,  but I am stuck at hash[key]=>value

```
file_data = {} 
File.open('input.txt', 'r') do |file| 
  file.each_line do |line| 
     line_data = line.split('=') 
     file_data[line_data[0]] = line_data[1]
   end 
end 
puts file_data
```

Comment: I tried and i did not told you to do my homework for free. i read the data from the file and store every line into array but i am stuck at hash[key]=>value

Comment: file_data = {}
File.open('input.txt', 'r') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    line_data = line.split('=')
    file_data[line_data[0]] = line_data[1]
   end
end

puts file_data

Comment: @anjalirai Next time, please do share your code so that others can guide further.  I have added your code to your question.  Feel free to edit your question to add more details if need be

Comment: Sure hope those emails (and potential mobile numbers) are under your control...posting them out like that on the Internet is pretty dangerous.

Comment: Thanks.. Next time i will share proper code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that each line in your input file has pattern of `key=value` strings which are separated by commas, you need to split the line first around comma, and then around equals sign.  Here is version of corrected code:

```
# Need to collect parsed data from each line into an array
array_of_file_data = []

File.open('input.txt', 'r') do |file| 

  file.each_line do |line| 

     #create a hash to collect data from each line
     file_data = {} 

     # First split by comma
     pairs = line.chomp.split(", ")

     pairs.each do |p|
        #Split by = to separate out key and value
        key_value = p.split('=') 
        file_data[key_value[0]] = key_value[1]  
     end

     array_of_file_data << file_data
   end 
end 
puts array_of_file_data
```

Above code will print:

```
{"Name"=>"Ashok", "Email"=>"ashok85@gmail.com", "Country"=>"India", "Comments"=>"9898984512"}
{"Email"=>"raju@hotmail.com", "Country"=>"Sri Lanka", "Name"=>"Raju"}
{"Country"=>"India", "Comments"=>"45535878", "Email"=>"vijay@gmail.com", "Name"=>"Vijay"}
{"Name"=>"Ashok", "Country"=>"India", "Email"=>"ashok37@live.com", "Comments"=>"8898788987"}
```

---

A more complete version of program is given below.

```
hash_array = []

# Parse the lines and store it in hash array
File.open("sample.txt", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
       # Splits are done around , and = preceded or followed 
       # by any number of white spaces
       splits = line.chomp.split(/\s*,\s*/).map{|p| p.split(/\s*=\s*/)}

       # to_h can be used to convert an array with even number of elements
       # into a hash, by treating it as an array of key-value pairs
       hash_array << splits.to_h 
    end
end

# Sort the array of hashes
hash_array = hash_array.sort {|i, j| i["Name"] <=> j["Name"]}

# Print the output, more tricks needed to get it better formatted
header = ["Name", "Email", "Country", "Comments"]
puts header.join(" ")
hash_array.each do |h|
    puts h.values_at(*header).join(" ")
end
```

Above program outputs:

```
Name Email Country Comments
Ashok ashok85@gmail.com India 9898984512
Ashok ashok37@live.com India 8898788987
Raju raju@hotmail.com Sri Lanka 
Vijay vijay@gmail.com India 45535878
```

You may want to refer to [Padding printed output of tabular data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603047/padding-printed-output-of-tabular-data) to have better formatted tabular output

Comment: Sorting part had a bug, fixed now.